# git verify trusted tags

Tags: git, digital-signature, gnupg, pki

I would like to include `git tag -v` command into the deployment process to catch unsigned tags or tags signed by a non-trusted GPG key.

The command returns with an exit code of `0` if the tag has a valid signature, but does not care wether the signed key is trusted or not.

I don't want to resort to grepping the resulting GPG message manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried it yet, and the documentation doesn't mention exit codes, but you could try

[git-verify-tag](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-verify-tag.html) plumbing command

---

**Update** Having no easy way to test this, I've reviewed the source code:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/81b50f3ce40bfdd66e5d967bf82be001039a9a98/builtin/verify-tag.c

It does appear to consciously return the relevant result codes, so I'd expect this to work

Comment: Exit code seems correct. Using `git verify-tag t1 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?` will print `0` on success and `1` on error.