# Combined command for git tag verification and git checkout?

Tags: git, security, verification, git-checkout, git-tag

Usual work flow is, git tag verify.

```
git tag -v tagname
```

Then git tag checkout.

```
git checkout tagname
```

Is there a combined command to verify the tag, shows the verification, and checks it out if verification succeeded?

Comment: Tried setting up an alias in your `.gitconfig` to chain the commands in your workflow?

Comment: It would be important to see if the tag verification actually worked.

Comment: Seems like you might be able to lean on the return code of `git verify-tag` (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010472/git-verify-trusted-tags) for this.

Comment: Is it possible to tie it to a key fingerprint? Otherwise any trusted key in the keyring would be able to create a legit signature?

Comment: You could use the `post-checkout` hook to check if the refspec is a tag and verify it there, and fail verbosely if it is invalid.

Answer (score 5):

In a bash shell:

```
git tag -v tagname && git checkout tagname
```

That would only work [if the first command succeeds](https://superuser.com/a/235762/141).

That can be part, for instance, of a `post-receive` hook.
Or it can be made an independent command:

Even on windows, a script name `git-ctag` (put anywhere in the `%PATH%`) would enable you to type git `ctag <atag>`, which would checkout the tag only if the verification step passes.

```
#!/bin/bash
git tag -v $1 && git checkout $1
```

Comment: How to check, that the signature was made by an accepted/valid OpenPGP fingerprint?

Comment: @adrelanos you can use `git verify-tag` (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-verify-tag), as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/8010472/6309

Comment: One problem, it's only using short OpenPGP fingerprints, which are not safe and doesn't allow passing extra options to gnupg.

Comment: @adrelanos nothing in https://github.com/git/git/blob/18d0fec24027ac226dc2c4df2b955eef2a16462a/builtin/verify-tag.c suggests that short OpenPGP fingerprints are used though. Where did you see that?

Comment: @adrelanos actually, the code that could use short or long fingerprint would be https://github.com/git/git/blob/63a45136a329bab550425c3142db6071434d935e/gpg-interface.c.