# How to verify a git commit at which a git tag is pointing?

Tags: git, security, commit, verification, gnupg

I understand, one can verify signed git:

- [commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371955/verifying-signed-git-commits) and
- [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010472/git-verify-trusted-tags).

But how to verify the git commit at which some tag is pointing? Using this at the moment.

```
git verify-commit "$(git rev-list --max-count 1 tag-name)"
```

`git rev-list --max-count 1 tag-name` to figure out at which commit the tag is pointing and then passing that to `git verify-commit`.

Is there a simpler way?

Does this look sane, secure?

(What's the background of this? Related to [git sha 1 and git security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67920/how-safe-are-signed-git-tags-only-as-safe-as-sha-1-or-somehow-safer).)

Comment: `git verify-commit tag-name^{commit}` ?  I don't use GPG so can't test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tag^{commit}` or `tag^{}` resolves to the commit to which a tag points.

So the following should do what you want:

```
git verify-commit tag^{}
```

Comment: 7 years later but your answer is still appreciated!

Comment: Note that when using `zsh` as shell this has to be quoted: `git verify-commit "tag^{}"`